# Gluon - Error on compile to IOS Simulator - x86_64-apple-ios

Tags: java, ios, maven, gluon

After the release 1.0.12 on last Feb 3, 2022 I tried to compile one project on macbook pro with xcode 12 to test on Iphone simulator. But I'd got the following error:

```
mvn -Pios-sim gluonfx:compile

[seg. fev. 07 21:23:35 BRT 2022][INFO] We will now compile your code for x86_64-apple-ios. This may take some time.
[seg. fev. 07 21:23:36 BRT 2022][INFO] Downloading JavaFX static libs...
[seg. fev. 07 21:23:36 BRT 2022][SEVERE] Downloading failed: https://download2.gluonhq.com/substrate/javafxstaticsdk/openjfx-18-ea+10-ios-x86_64-static.zip
Check the log files under /Users/macbook/Documents/workspace/AgrotechApp/target/gluonfx/x86_64-ios/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error downloading zips: Error: /Users/macbook/.gluon/substrate/openjfx-18-ea+10-ios-x86_64-static.zip does not exist
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.setupDependencies(FileDeps.java:348)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.resolvePath(FileDeps.java:181)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.getJavaFXSDKLibsPath(FileDeps.java:114)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AbstractTargetConfiguration.processClassPath(AbstractTargetConfiguration.java:746)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AbstractTargetConfiguration.validateCompileRequirements(AbstractTargetConfiguration.java:346)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AbstractTargetConfiguration.compile(AbstractTargetConfiguration.java:130)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.SubstrateDispatcher.nativeCompile(SubstrateDispatcher.java:425)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeCompileMojo.execute(NativeCompileMojo.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    ... org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.327 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-07T21:23:36-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.12:compile (default-cli) on project agrotechapp: Error: Error downloading zips: Error: /Users/macbook/.gluon/substrate/openjfx-18-ea+10-ios-x86_64-static.zip does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

[compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx5EV.png)

[download error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEeLT.png)

Comment: Can you try it a second time? The very first time some dependencies are downloaded but the path for `javafxstaticsdk` is wrong. Trying again might fix that as the other dependencies are already downloaded.

Comment: Hi José. Yes I tried many times.
I've tried to access the link on browser https://download2.gluonhq.com/substrate/javafxstaticsdk/openjfx-18-ea+10-ios-x86_64-static.zip and I'd got the error: "http 404 on nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)"

Comment: Did you run `mvn -Pios gluonfx:compile` before? Even if you don't have an iOS device, that will install some dependencies that are needed for the iOS-simulator too. Then try again `mvn -Pios-sim gluonfx:compile`.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, you can do:
`export JAVAFX_STATIC_SDK_PATH=/Users/macbook/.gluon/substrate/javafxStaticSdk/18-ea+10/ios-arm64/sdk`, and then try `mvn -Pios-sim gluonfx:compile`.

Comment: The solution to run mvn -Pios gluonfx:compile first it worked! Build Success after run mvn -Pios-sim gluonfx:compile. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, good to know. I'll file an issue to indicate this in the docs